# How can i do a count of two columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i want to do a count of two columns in mysql. One of the columns is a string but another is a date like 06/08/2017 and when i do my query i get 0 results.

```html
SELECT count(*) FROM `castigos` WHERE inicio_normal=05/06/2017 AND cod_emplazamiento=1
```

I have entries of that data but its dont show me anything. Maybe the type of data in the date is wrong?

What should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the date field to your select and group by it.  Otherwise mysql extensions doesn't recognize you want to group by the date and will aggregrate all the results into 1 column.  And since you are getting 0 count, you're where clause must not be working.

Your date format seems malformed. usually YYYY/MM/DD format (standard format); 
or specify a format using `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('17/09/2010','%d/%m/%Y');`

[MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

the below uses the implicit casting and default date format to convert the string date to a valid date.

```
SELECT inicio_normal, count(*) 
FROM `castigos` 
WHERE inicio_normal='2017/05/06' 
  AND cod_emplazamiento=1 
GROUP BY inicio_normal
```

Otherwise its doing math and comparing that date to the number stored for the date.

Understand dates should be stored in a date datatype and when you query dates you're passing in a string that is being cast to a date datatype for comparison.  So you need to use the standard format, or cast your string to a date so the db engine knows how to convert your format to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `castigos` WHERE inicio_normal="05/06/2017" AND cod_emplazamiento=1 GROUP BY inicio_normal
```

Comment: Need to handle the fact that mySQL will only return 1 row here since there's no group by. and the expected results show counts for each date in data.

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE inicio_normal=05/06/2017

If you divide 3 by 6 then by 2017 you get a very small value indeed. OTOH if you [reformat this as a date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) (e.g. 20170605, if you gave us a European formatted date - dd/mm/yyyy) then your query will find the rows you showed us.